# Inner workings of JPA

Tags: java, jpa, entity, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I really don't get it.

If I persist a new item then use it to get the **autogenerated key**, it fails:

```
class BookManagerBean {
    @PersistentContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void addBook(Book book)  {           
            em.persist(book);                   
    }
}
//...somewhere else
@GetThisObjectByJNDI-OrInject
BookManagerRemote bookManager;    

Book book = new Book("Writer","Title");
bookManager.addBook(book);
book.getBookid() //<--NULL, didn't get synched, but new data with id in DB is fine
```

But if I return the persisted item, it works:

```
class BookManagerBean {
    @PersistentContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Book addBook(Book book)  {           
            em.persist(book);
            return book;                    
    }
}

//...somewhere else
@GetThisObjectByJNDI-OrInject
BookManagerRemote bookManager;    

Book book = new Book("Writer","Title");
bookManager.book = addBook(book);
book.getBookid() // <--- Auto-generated id is right here! It's synched!
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What persistence provider are you using? Hibernate? EclipseLink?

Comment: Check that the book returned is the same instance passed into addBook.  Serialization might be occurring when passing it remotely.

Comment: @Chris I update my code to reflect where / what kind of beans do I use in the process. This might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are accessing BookManagerBean remotely, or as a remote, so the Book it being serialized, so the id is assigned to a different copy, and can only be accessed from the client if you return it.

Either return it, or change you bean to be local, not remote.

Comment: You're right! I was accessing the bookManager via BookManagerRemote interface.